# didAddNode vs SceneKit Collision Detection

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I am building a small demo where two objects can collide with each other. Basically an object will be placed on a plane. I have the following code for adding physics body to the plane.

```
 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        if anchor is ARPlaneAnchor {


            let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.5, height: 0.5)
            let material = SCNMaterial()
            material.isDoubleSided = true
            material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "overlay_grid")
            plane.firstMaterial = material

            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: nil)
            planeNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.plane.rawValue

            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = .pi/2

            node.addChildNode(planeNode)

}
```

Even though the plane gets added it does not participate in any physical collisions. If I try to place objects on it, it goes right through it. But if I change the last line to the following it works:

```
// node.addChildNode(planeNode) // INSTEAD OF THIS
   planeNode.position = SCNVector3(anchor.transform.columns.3.x, anchor.transform.columns.3.y, anchor.transform.columns.3.z)
 self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode) // THIS WORKS
```

My understanding is that all the collision related stuff is maintained by SceneView and in order to participate in collisions I need to add it to the SceneView hierarchy instead of the ARSCNView hierarchy.

QUESTION:

```
// node.addChildNode(planeNode) // WHY THIS DOES NOT WORK
   planeNode.position = SCNVector3(anchor.transform.columns.3.x, anchor.transform.columns.3.y, anchor.transform.columns.3.z)

 self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode) // WHY THIS WORKS
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Please see the updated question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` physics bodies are so named because they aren’t supposed to move (relative to the global/world/scene coordinate space). Many optimizations in the inner workings of a physics engine depend on this, so changing the position of a node with an attached static physics body is likely to cause incorrect behavior.

ARKit continually moves the `ARPlaneAnchor`s that result from plane detection — the longer it looks at a real-world planar surface, from more different angles, the better it knows the position and size of that plane.

When you add a child node to the `ARSCNView`-managed node in `renderer(_:didAdd:for:)`, the child node’s `position` may not change... but that position is relative to its parent node, and ARKit automatically moves the parent node to match the `ARPlaneAnchor` it goes with. So the child node moves relative to the world whenever ARKit updates the plane anchor. If you have a static physics body on that node, you get weirdness.

When you directly add a node as a child of the scene’s `rootNode` and set its position *based on* the *initial* of a plane anchor, that node stays still — *you’re* the only one setting its world-space position, and you’re doing so exactly once. So it’s safe to give it a static physics body.

(Note that if you want “static” physics body behavior for something that can change over time, it is possible to delete the physics body and re-create it at a new position. Just don’t do so too often or you’re probably defeating other optimizations in the physics engine.)

Comment: I def did not added the complete scenario. The static body was the floor and I was dropping on top of the floor. The objects were just passing through the floor. But when I added them to the SceneKit rootNode they start colliding.